# Debugging logon code

Tags: c#

I have some code for a login feature. I cannot get the return statement to be recognized inside of the try statement, which seems like the only logical place to put it. Where the return statement is currently allows a user to log in even if the password is incorrect. If I put the return statement anywhere else I receive the error "not all code paths return a value".

```
    public static User selectUser(string userName, string password)
    {
       // code to validate user
        try
        {
                if (isUserValid)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login successful!");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login failed");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
             MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
        return aUser;
    }
```

Comment: `I cannot get the return statement to be recognized inside of the try statement` What do you mean by "recognized"? Do you get a compiler error?

Comment: There is no need to add thankyounotes, also I've removed some unrelated code from sample...

Comment: most of the suggested answers use exception handling and still require the calling code to `if-else` the result. I updated my downvoted answer to explain myself. Hope it helps the OP to avoid exception based programming like solutions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should return the user object only during the sucess scenarios, else return null. In-order to determine whether user has be authenitcated or not check for user object vs null when consuming the selectUser method

```
User aUser = null;
try {
            while (dbReader.Read())
            {
                if (dbReader.HasRows)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login successful!");
                    aUser = new User();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login failed");
                }
            }
        }

catch (Exception e) {
                        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                    }
finally {
          return aUser;
}
```

Comment: Your code have exactly the same issue as original code "not all code paths return a value"...

Comment: You must also add a return null; statement after the while loop. If the DbReader does not return any rows, you must return null,ergo, unable to login.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov checkout my updated answer, I didn't realize there was another if block

Comment: This post and the comments put me on the right track. I also solved it by moving some code that opens the next form from my presentation layer to the if statement in the code I posted. I have this pretty much figured out now! Thanks to everyone for the help.

Comment: +1. Looks fine to me now. @user1729696, clearly your `string password` named wrong as it should contain password's hash... and eating all exceptions if bad practice...

Comment: @user1729696 I would suggest you to use [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) pattern do dispose the object properly

Answer (score 3):

MSDN have very good example of error in explanation of error code you get - [CS0161](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87cz4k9t%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Your sample have multiple "code paths" - meaning sequence of commands executed based on the conditions in if/try statements.

Here are main possible path:

1. user is valid, no exceptions: try block, message box 1, end of function
2. user is invalid, no exceptions: try block, message box 2, end of function
3. exception during validation: try bloc, `catch` block, end of function

If you return result only from some of the code path (i.e. 1 and 2 as in the question) and remove `return` from "end of function" only 2 of 3 code paths will have return statement.

Fix in your case could be to always `return null;` at the end of function and jump out with `return validatedUser;` from places you have valid user object.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static User selectUser(string userName, string password)
    {
        User aUser = new User();
        if (sConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            sConnection.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = sConnection.CreateCommand();
        OleDbDataReader dbReader = null;
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE ([userName]='" + userName + "' AND [Password]='" + password + "')";
                        cmd.CommandText = sql;
            dbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            while (dbReader.Read())
            {
                if (dbReader.HasRows)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login successful!");
                    aUser.UserName = username;
                    return aUser;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login failed");
                    aUser.UserName =string.empty;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                aUser.UserName = string.empty;
            }
        return aUser;
    }
```

After you invoke this function, check the return IsNULLofEmpty(aUser.Username)

Answer (score 2):

Yes C# will not allow you if there exist at least one flow that does not return a variable
of the type User.
Your code should work fine, as it does return a variable of the type User.
What you should do is, dont display the message inside ur function
implement it at the place from where u r calling it, just put a try catch
block around the calling statement so that you know what is happening when
the user does not exist (the object returned by the function must have some
properties you can check from)

In that case u probably can check the function returned value in if else condition
to display the message accordingly

Comment: Your answer would be nice if you avoid "u", "ur" and thr shrtng f txt.

Answer (score -1):

Handle the exception in your view logic instead of in your business logic.

Something like this:

```
class View
{
    public void Login(string username, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            var user = _users.SelectUser(username, password);
            MessageBox.Show(
                string.Format("valid user: {0}", user.UserName));
        }
        catch (InvalidUserNameOrPasswordException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password");
        }
    }
}

public class Users
{
    public User SelectUser(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (!ValidUser)
        {
            throw InvalidUserNameOrPasswordException();
        }

        return new User();
    }
}
```

Note that this solution does **not** require calling code to `if-else` the result of the method.

-- update --

Only catching the InvalidUserNameOrPasswordException now

-- update2 --

The point I am trying to make is that exception based programming is suggested and accepted as solution. For further reference, read through [this (sarcastic) post where exception based programming](http://blog.arc90.com/2008/04/01/exception-based-programming-a-primer/) is explained in a fun and somewhat sarcastic fashion.

Comment: Even if this *did* solve the problem, this would be bad advice. You're using exceptions for flow control. The real answer is that he shouldn't be catching the base `Exception` class at all.

Comment: @CodyGray ah you're right. misread the question, noticed some sql stuff, didn't realize he was doing everything in his view. my point was that he shouldn't handle the exception in his businesslogic but handle it in his view instead.

Comment: @CodyGray still convinced that this is the wrong solution? Interesting!

Comment: What, because I didn't respond within a few minutes you assumed I had to still think it was the wrong solution? Not necessarily... Sometimes I just get up from the keyboard. Anyway, this is better, but you're still using exceptions for flow control. I suppose that's a debatable issue of style, but most people are generally in agreement that it's not the best way to go. Why can't the `SelectUser` method just return `null` if there is no valid user matching the specified parameters? Then there's no reason to throw and immediately catch an exception.

Comment: @CodyGray Since we *are* relying on exceptions (OP decided that in his question), then use them for what they are intended for (which is, indeed, control the flow). The problem I have with the suggested answers, is that the exception is handled internally (in the `SelectUser` method, just to set the result to `null` and then force the calling side to `if-else` the result. In the end, exceptions *are* intended to control flow. Not to use it in a exception based programming way like is suggested (and accepted...).